# complexity of a simple procedure

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o

I have a procedure:

```
procedure A(n) 
begin 
 i:=j:=1
 while i < n do begin 
     i:=i+i
     for k:=1 to i do j:=j+1
 end
end
```

My problem is - I know the while loop runs `log(n)` times, but I am not exactly sure how many times does the whole program run? 
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Am I right that it will run in `O(nlogn)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop executed log(Base2)n -1 times.so it is O(log(Base2)n).
The for loop executed i times for each iteration of the while loop.now in each iteration of the while loop i gets incremented to i+i.so total number of for loop iteration=1+2+4+8+...2^(log(Base2)n-1)=2^((log(base2)n-1)+1)-1/2-1=n-1.so the for loop is O(n).
So total time complexity=O(log(Base2)n+O(n)=O(n).

Comment: why is it O(log(Base2)n+O(n)? the for loop is in the why loop so shouldn't it be O(logn *n)?

Comment: I have considered all the iterations of the inner for loop.so after summing all iterations i,e 1+2+4+... 2^(log(Base2)n-1) it becomes total number of for loop iteration(now independent of outer while loop).and total time complexity is time complexity of outer loop+complexity of inner loop.it is the aggregate analysis and in this way you got tighter bound.

Comment: your assumption is also correct that it is O(nlogn).but it is not tight enough.So using aggregate analysis you get the tighter upper bound which is O(n).let me know if you still have some problem.